# Как запретить изменение переменной?

Tags: java, классы, переменные, доступ, константа

Как сделать, чтобы переменную можно было изменять только из текущего класса и при обращении из других классов она была, грубо говоря, как "константа", то есть с доступом только на чтение?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не припомню таких спецификаторов в языке ***Java***. Но можно сделать, например, `private` поле с  `public getter()` и  **НЕ** `public setter()`.

Comment: Какой смысл приватного сеттера? Мы в текущем классе и так можем изменять значение полей. Разве что в сеттере какая-то магия происходит кроме изменения...

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Может вы захотите сделать protected setter()  - минус не оправдан

Comment: @LexHobbit, вы уж определитесь: private, protected.... Теперь, когда вы внесли изменения, vможет и не оправдан. Но мой минус здесь это плюс чуть ниже, в варианте без сеттера.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Извините, без комментариев...

Answer (score 3):

Если нужен доступ в режиме readonly, то можно написать примерно так:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public int getBar()
    {
        return bar;
    }
}
```